# Difference between arrays with " " and () in bash script?

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell

I have two examples of a bash script.  All I do is just use `sed` to replace some strings in a file.  The file is specified when the script is run.  So, you would run it like `./replace_file.sh input_file`.

```
hug="g h 7"

for elm in $hug
do
  echo "replacing $elm"
  sed -i'_backup' "s/$elm/BOO/g" $1
done
```

and

```
hug=('g' 'h' '7')

for elm in $hug
do
  echo "replacing $elm"
  sed -i'_backup' "s/$elm/BOO/g" $1
done
```

The first script above, echos the following:

```
replacing g
replacing h
replacing 7
```

But, the second one stops after `replace g`.  It is unclear to me why.  Can someone please shed some light?

Thank you.

Comment: (why exactly did you tag PHP here? - just curious)

Comment: I meant to do `cli`  typo sorry!

Comment: `for elm in ${hug[@]}` in the case of the array... You can quote `"${hug[@]}"` to preserve whitespace in the elements (if they have any -- you don't) Attempting to call an array *without* braces, e.g. `{...[@]}`, you are simply referencing the first element of the array, `'g'` in your case.

Comment: `hug="g h 7"` doesn't create an array at all; it just creates a string with whitespace in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As set forth in the comment, when you attempt to iterate over the elements in the array by calling `for elm in $hug`, you are simply referencing the first element in the array. To iterate over the elements in the array, you use the array syntax, e.g. `${array[@]}` to access each element sequentially (and you can quote the array to preserve whitespace in the elements.) In your case you need only:

```
#!/bin/bash

hug=('g' 'h' '7')

for elm in ${hug[@]}
do
echo "replacing $elm"
# sed -i'_backup' "s/$elm/BOO/g" $1
done
```

**Output**

```
$ bash arrayiter.sh
replacing g
replacing h
replacing 7
```

Comment: Needs quotes around the `${hug[@]}` to avoid string-splitting. Try `hug=( "foo bar" "baz qux" )` to observe the bug in this as currently written.

Comment: Now I'm confused. I noted you should quote to preserve whitespace (prevent word-splitting), but his elements are `'g'`, `'h'`, and `'7'`. so I left it as a note. Did I miss something?

Comment: If the elements of the array do not contain whitespace, then it doesn't matter if you quote it or not; the result is the same. But if even one item *does* contain whitespace, it is crucial that you quote the expansion.